# How to maintain an order on child records when using Rails' accepts_nested_attributes_for feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am using Rails' nifty `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for creating `invoices` and their `items`. `Items` can be added dynamically to an `invoice` with jQuery.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :number, :date, :recipient, :items_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

This works fine. Except for the **order** in which Rails saves the `items`.

For example when I create an `invoice` with these 5 `items`...

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

... everything works fine. But when I then hit `Create` to save the invoice plus items to the database, the order is completely randomised, for example like this:

```
D
A
C
E
B
```

A peek into my database and the `created_at` column of my `items` table revealed that Rails (or SQLite?) seemingly saves the `items` in a random order and not in the order in which I (as a user) added them to the `invoice`.

Is this normal behaviour and if so how can I maintain a proper ordering on the `items` that I add to my `invoice`?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the order in which association objects are received by passing an :order option to your association. For example:

```
has_many :items, :order => "created_at DESC"
```

source: [association options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics#options-for-has_many)

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. But actually that line doesn't make any difference. The problem is that the `items` are **saved** to the database in a *random* order. Is there any way for Rails to detect in what order I added them to the `invoice`?

Comment: My solution proposes how your child objects are retrieved, so if you were to query for an invoices child items to display them to the client or for processing you would see them in the order specified by the options hash. Just to clarify, is there another reason why you need to have them ordered in a specific way in the database?

Comment: I am building an invoicing application and the `items` should always appear in the exact order in which they were added. The critical moment is the moment the `invoice` gets saved for the first time. Because that save completely jumbles all the `items` that were just added to the form. That's not acceptable from a user's point of view.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, from a users point of view the items would be listed in order of the created_at with the above solution, or in whatever order you specify in the order option so long as you're retrieving the items through the association and not a separate select. Is this making any sense? If it's not working for you show me how you're retrieving your items and we can debug from there.

Comment: It is not working because all these items have the same created_at value. Also as they are saved in random order that ordering by ID doesn't have sense too. I guess this randomness is connected with fact with that your version of ruby (for ex. 1.8) may not respect hash (params) elements order.